# Custom action on login and "remember me"

Tags: hooks, login

I try to call a function everytime a user login to website.

I succeeded with the `wp_login` hook for user who fill the login form.

However I can't find a hook for an user which has the "remember me" option activated when he come back to website (so he already have a login cookie).

I checked `wp_validate_auth_cookie()` function but this one is fired on each page: is Wordpress doing a check for "remember me" cookie on each page and then set user logged?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `wp_login` hook. Use `wp_signon` function instead.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/

```
wp_signon( array $credentials = array(), string|bool $secure_cookie = '' )
```

> The credentials is an array that has ‘user_login’, ‘user_password’,
>   and ‘remember’ indices. If the credentials is not given, then the log
>   in form will be assumed and used if set.

Comment: But `wp_signon()` function is only called when you submit login form. What about an user who come back to website another day (and is automatically logged by "remember me" option) ?

Comment: @fdehanne Then it is not clear what you're trying to do. There is no such thing as remember me hook.

Answer (score 1):

[wp_login](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) hook pass two parameters: $user->user_login (string) and $user ( [WP_User](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) ). "remember me" option on login form did not pass on wp_login hook, its used on the [wp_signon](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) function to set the cookie on the browser.

```
wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, $credentials['remember'], $secure_cookie);
```

So you can't access that using wp_login hook.

Comment: I know I can't access to it from `wp_login` hook, so I'm looking for another hook called for users with "remember me" option activated when they come back to website another day (and are automatically logged in).

Comment: There is no hook available to check remember post value, as its only used to set cookie on browser while login.

Comment: I think there a misunderstanding : I don't want to get post value. When an user load a page how is he set logged to website by Wordpress when he already has this "remember me" cookie? (I've added more information on my question)

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you are trying to do, but in order to get the Remember Me status, you can do the following:

1. Call `wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, $remember )`, where `$remember` is the Remember Me status.
2. If you need to customize the actual session length based on the Remember Me setting, add a filter for the cookie expiration: `add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'get_expiration' ), 10, 3 );` with:

```
function get_expiration( $expiration, $user_id, $remember ) {
    // $remember will be passed from wp_set_auth_cookie()
    if ( $remember ) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but from what I understand, OP needs to call a custom function *every* time a user logs in (regardless of if it's via the login form or automatically logging in as a result of checking the Remember Me option during a prior login).
This can be achieved by using the 'authenticate' filter. More information can be found in this helpful guide that I found.

https://usersinsights.com/wordpress-user-login-hooks/